# QGIS plugin to publish to geoserver

Tags: geoserver, qgis

Is there a QGIS plugin to plublish layers to Geoserver and/or to plublish layers/maps to GeoNode?

Answer (score 0):

the processing toolbox (formerly sextante?) provides scripts for that. See this tutorial:
http://qgissextante.blogspot.com.au/2013/02/bulk-importing-into-geoserver.html

Comment: Try to include a more detailed answer, and try not to rely on links too much.
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Answer (score 0):

Just as update for anyone looking at this question, in 2014 boundless released a [qgis plugin](http://qgis.boundlessgeo.com/static/docs/intro.html) to interact with opengeo suite, but it is suitable to be used with any geoserver installation.

It allows upload vector and raster layers using the REST Api of geoserver, modify styles (with some limitations) and another couple of thins.

Answer (score 0):

a new plugin has bee released for qgis/geoserver
http://boundlessgeo.com/2015/12/announcing-the-new-geoserver-qgis-plugin/